# Javascript Console Redirect Tag

Tags: javascript

What is redirect tag javascript console? Please help, me very need this tag.

I try it make:

```
}else if(command.match(/ ?(goto)/i)){
  con.logHTML(
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com' />
  );
```

Comment: Also write a properly detailed problem description. Hard to make much sense out of this as it is currently written. Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask]

Comment: Yes. But that been redirect with auto refresh when write command.